# What are the requirements of a collection type when model binding?

Tags: collections, binding, asp.net-mvc-2

I have been reviewing model binding with collections, specifically going through this article

http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx

However, the model I would like to use in my code does not implement collections using generic lists. Instead it uses its own collection classes, which inherit from a custom generic collection base class, the declaration of which is

```
public abstract class CollectionBase<T> : IEnumerable<T>
```

The collections in my POSTed action method are all non-null, but contain no elements.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to code my own view model, with generic lists in place of the collection classes.